# How to get the "Dedicated GPU memory" number for every running process in Windows (The same numbers that are shown in the Windows Task Manager)

Tags: c++, windows, winapi, memory, gpu

The Windows Task Manager, in the "Details" tab, shows the "Dedicated GPU memory" usage for every process. For example, I can currently see that chrome.exe uses 1.4 GB Dedicated GPU memory, dwm.exe uses 1.3 GB Dedicated GPU memory, and firefox.exe uses 0.78 GB Dedicated GPU memory.

I want to get that exact same data from my own C++ code. How can I do that in the easiest way?

I know that the Windows Task Manager only has that data since Windows 10, and I am fine with a solution that only works on Windows 10 and above.

The exact goal of my code is to find every process that uses more than 0.2 GB of Dedicated GPU memory. I want to have that information to show a message to the user of my software recommending closing those specific processes, because my software will run better if it has as much VRAM as possible available for itself.

Comment: You can have a look at how process hacker does it: https://processhacker.sourceforge.io/

Comment: @SimonMourier interesting! Unfortunately, it seems that software shows quite incorrect data regarding the "Dedicated GPU memory" usage of a process. It shows way lower numbers for every process than the Windows Task Manager. firefox.exe shows up as 900 MB in Task Manager, but only as 200 MB in Process Hacker. devenv.exe is 630 MB in Task Manager, but only 77 MB in Process Hacker. So wherever that software gets its data from seems to not be a good source.

Comment: With a quick test with FF on my PC, PH2's "GPU dedicated bytes" column (version 2.29.124) seems to indicate the same memory as TaskMan's "Dedicated GPU memory" column.

Comment: @SimonMourier I am also using 2.29.124. And also comparing the "GPU dedicated bytes" column with the "Dedicated GPU memory" column. And I see them being very different.

Comment: You can check with [Process Explorer](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/process-explorer) which can also show *Dedicated GPU memory*.

Comment: "Dear user, this program works better if you close dwm.exe."

Comment: @YangXiaoPo-MSFT As far as I know, Process Explorer is not open source, so it can't help me to figure out how to do it from C++.

Comment: @IInspectable I'd of course put the dwm.exe on a blacklist so that it would not be shown to the user as something they should close ;)

Comment: @JohnAl It can help you identify whether *Process Hacker* has a good data source or not.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Task manager and third party software are using performance counters to query the dedicated GPU memory information. For example you can execute these counters from powershell:

```
Get-Counter -Counter "\GPU Engine(*)\*"
Get-Counter -Counter "\GPU Engine(*)\Running Time"
Get-Counter -Counter "\GPU Engine(*)\Utilization Percentage"

Get-Counter -Counter "\GPU Local Adapter Memory(*)\*"
Get-Counter -Counter "\GPU Local Adapter Memory(*)\Local Usage"

Get-Counter -Counter "\GPU Non Local Adapter Memory(*)\*"
Get-Counter -Counter "\GPU Non Local Adapter Memory(*)\Non Local Usage"

Get-Counter -Counter "\GPU Process Memory(*)\*"
Get-Counter -Counter "\GPU Process Memory(*)\Dedicated Usage"
Get-Counter -Counter "\GPU Process Memory(*)\Local Usage"
Get-Counter -Counter "\GPU Process Memory(*)\Non Local Usage"
Get-Counter -Counter "\GPU Process Memory(*)\Shared Usage"
Get-Counter -Counter "\GPU Process Memory(*)\Total Committed"
```

You can query the same counters from c++ using the PdhAddCounter function. For example:

```
PdhAddCounter(..., L"\\GPU Process Memory(*)\\Dedicated Usage", ...)
```