# Retrieving the amount of available adapter memory in DirectX 11

Tags: directx, directx-11, directx-12

DirectX 9 had `IDirect3DDevice9::GetAvailableTextureMem()` which gives an estimate. I cannot readily find the equivalent in DirectX 11.

I found `DXGI_ADAPTER_DESC.DedicatedVideoMemory` which gives me the total, but what I’d like in addition to that is the amount currently used (or currently free) in a quick and efficient manner.

There must be a way as Windows Task Manager has a GPU memory usage graph on the Performance tab.

Any pointer?

I could not find any method or field in the documentation.

Comment: It's not only DirectX related. Look here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73476947/how-to-get-the-dedicated-gpu-memory-number-for-every-running-process-in-window The equivalent of the global per machine measure that taskman shows seems to be `Get-Counter -Counter "\GPU Adapter Memory(*)\Dedicated Usage"` + `Get-Counter -Counter "\GPU Adapter Memory(*)\Shared Usage"`

Comment: See also the [VideoMemory](https://github.com/walbourn/directx-sdk-samples/tree/main/VideoMemory) sample.